I keep getting an "Unexpected end of JSON input" error when submitting a sign up form
I'm honestly kind of new to react, and when trying to submit a signup form after filling out the details, I keep getting the error "Unexpected end of JSON input", and on my node terminal it shows this:
11:58:50 PM [vite] http proxy error: /api/auth/signup
AggregateError [ECONNREFUSED]:
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1116:18)    
    at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1683:7)

this is the code block:
import { useState } from "react";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { useAuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";

const useSignup = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const { setAuthUser } = useAuthContext();

    const signup = async ({ fullName, username, password, confirmPassword, gender }) => {
        const success = handleInputErrors({ fullName, username, password, confirmPassword, gender });
        if (!success) return;

        setLoading(true);
        try {
            const res = await fetch("/api/auth/signup", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify({ fullName, username, password, confirmPassword, gender }),
            });

            const data = await res.json();
            if (data.error) {
                throw new Error(data.error);
            }
            localStorage.setItem("chat-user", JSON.stringify(data));
            setAuthUser(data);
        } catch (error) {
            toast.error(error.message);
        } finally {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    };

    return { loading, signup };
};
export default useSignup;

function handleInputErrors({ fullName, username, password, confirmPassword, gender }) {
    if (!fullName || !username || !password || !confirmPassword || !gender) {
        toast.error("Please fill in all fields");
        return false;
    }

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        toast.error("Passwords do not match");
        return false;
    }

    if (password.length < 6) {
        toast.error("Password must be at least 6 characters");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

hoping that this can be answered soon, thanks!
EDIT: The console on my browser shows that the error is happening on line 15, on the below portion:
try {
            const res = await fetch("/api/auth/signup", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify({ fullName, username, password, confirmPassword, gender }),
            });



If the "Unexpected end of JSON input" error is occurring at the fetch request, it suggests that the server response might be empty or not in the expected JSON format. To handle this, you can modify your code to catch this specific error and handle it accordingly.
const signup = async ({ fullName, username, password, confirmPassword, gender }) => {
const success = handleInputErrors({ fullName, username, password, confirmPassword, gender });
if (!success) return;
setLoading(true);
try {
    const res = await fetch("/api/auth/signup", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({ fullName, username, password, confirmPassword, gender }),
    });

    // Check if response is empty
    if (res.status === 204) {
        throw new Error("Empty response from the server");
    }

    const data = await res.json();

    if (data.error) {
        throw new Error(data.error);
    }

    localStorage.setItem("chat-user", JSON.stringify(data));
    setAuthUser(data);
} catch (error) {
    // If response is empty, handle it
    if (error instanceof SyntaxError && error.message === "Unexpected end of JSON input") {
        toast.error("Server response is empty or not in JSON format");
    } else {
        toast.error(error.message);
    }
} finally {
    setLoading(false);
}

};

To expand on this, the response is usually sending html to describe the actual cause of the error. Look into your network responses that are failing and you'll likely find a more accurate description of the source of the problem.

I got the "Server response is empty or not in JSON format". If so, where could I go to look for what's causing the error?
